# How to publish a new CompletableFuture result on an existing Observable?

Tags: java, request, observable, rx-java, completable-future

I will try to simplify the code and the problem I have as much as I can, but it seems to be a bit overcomplicated, so I am open for solutions with completely refactoring the code as well.

Briefly, the code is supposed to stream data continuously.
What I have is two merged Observables, one taking data from a REST request, one from another source. The first Observable gets the data through a CompletableFuture which is cancelled in case we got data faster from the other source. This mechanism was implemented to get data as fast as possible BUT to avoid making unnecessary REST requests and reach the API limit.

It is "easier" to understand by illustrating some code:

```
    public Disposable myMethod() {
        CompletableFuture restCallFuture = makeRequest();

        Observable restObservable = Observable.fromPublisher(s -> restCallFuture.thenAccept( obj -> s.onNext(obj))
            .exceptionally(throwable -> {
                if (throwable.getCause() instanceof CancellationException) {
                    //we are good
                });

        Observable otherObservable = getDataContinuouslyFromOtherSource();

        return Observable.merge(restObservable, otherObservable)
                .subscribe(obj -> {
                    restCallFuture.cancel(true);
                    doWhatever(obj);
                }
    }
```

The issue is, sometimes let's say the internet connection goes down and when it is up again, I get a notification. On this notification I want to repeat the REST request without restarting the application, and publish the data somehow on the same, already returned merged Observable instance. In fact, I want to repeat the entire request-cancel mechanism but without re-running the code, only by a function call.

I tried reinstantiating the CompletableFuture without losing the reference but it didn't work. I tried to read how can I somehow break this line:

```
Observable.fromPublisher(s -> restCallFuture.thenAccept( obj -> s.onNext(obj)));
```

and use something that is more suitable but didn't manage to figure anything out.

EDIT:
As per akarnokd's suggestion I am creating the restObservable in the following way:

```
Observable restObservable = ObservableInterop.fromFuture(restCallFuture);
```

I still don't know how to make it redo the REST call though.

Comment: Please don't do it this way but use a proper wrapper: [`FlowableInterop.fromFuture()`](https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJavaJdk8Interop/tree/master#completionstage-to-rxjava)

Comment: @akarnokd thank you for the suggestion, I didn't know about it before. Switched to ObservableInterop and it works. I have to read up on Flowable, is it something that is suited for this "repeating of future" issue that I have?

Comment: Futures are one shot so you have to recreate them like the first time.